# wifi doesn't work in software center

Tags: wireless, networking, software-center

i have a public wifi network which has wep security. it requires a key to establish connection and a username and password when i open a browser to surf.

but in software center there is no demand of username and password hence i can't use it to install anything on my ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

please give solution for this.

Comment: 1. connect to the WiFi. 2. Open browser and enter username and password. 3. Open Software Center and download and install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found the answer...
just open the terminal(ctrl+Alt+t) and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

enter your password if required.
Now this will open the `apt.conf` file in `/etc/apt` folder, here you can see your proxy
and port settings. in my case it is:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<a>172.18.0.1:3128/</a>";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<a>172.18.0.1:3128/</a>";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<a>172.18.0.1:3128/</a>/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://<a>172.18.0.1:3128/</a>";
```

now you have to just edit it by inserting your username and password for the network
like this:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@your.network.proxy:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@your.network.proxy:port/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@your.network.proxy:port/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://username:password@your.network.proxy:port/";
```

now save this....and you are done!!!

*HappyUbuntu*

Answer (score 2):

You should be launching a web browser first (Firefox/Chrome/etc), in all likelihood.

Within the browser, your access point (router, etc) should be providing you a login at that  point so you can authenticate in, get proper access out to the net, and at which point you should be able to get Software Center functionality.

Try opening a web browser, and see if you get auth requests from the access point.

Comment: i've done this before. it doesn't work.

Comment: If you open the web browser, and successfully authenticate/login, you shouldn't have any issues with using any internet connection except in the case where the WiFi provider or access point has some sort of blocking/port/IP restrictions setup.

What is the error you're getting, specifically?